# Как отрезать имя папки в TAR?

Tags: linux, tar

Делаю бекап так

```
tar Pczf "/mnt/hdd/backup1.jar"  "/var/www/index.php" "/var/www/second.php"
```

В результате в архиве лежит папка var, в ней www и только потом файлы. Как сделать, чтобы файлы были в корне архива?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте ключ -C, после него укажите базовую папку.

```
tar Pczf "/mnt/hdd/backup1.jar" -С "/var/www/" "index.php" "second.php"
```

Файлы *`index.php`* и *`second.php`* будут в корне архива.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ключ strip-components при распаковке - с ним можно распаковать файлы прямо в текущий каталог.